# JPA Bi-directional OneToMany does not give me the desired collection

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink

Im trying to map a oracle db model with JPA entities (Using eclipselink) - i have following simple setup :

table program with primary key id
table multi_kupon with compound primary keys id, spil and foreign key program_id

when i try to fetch program with a simple select i would expect the go get a list
of multi_kupon's but im getting a list of size 0. I've made certain that when i do
a select with joins i get data from both program and multi_kupon.

I believe that its got to do with my relations of the 2 entities - hope somebody can point me to my mistake(s)

Snippet from Entity 'Program' :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROGRAM", schema = "", catalog = "")
public class Program implements Serializable{

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private List<MultiKupon> MultiKuponList;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", fetch =  FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
  @JoinColumn(name = "spil", referencedColumnName = "spil")})
  public List<MultiKupon> getMultiKuponList() {
    return multiKuponList;
  }
```

Snippet from Entity 'MultiKupon' :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MULTI_KUPON", schema = "", catalog = "")
public class MultiKupon implements Serializable {

  private Integer id;
  private String spil;

  private Program program;

  @ManyToOne
  public Program getProgram() {
    return program;
  }
```

My stateless bean :

```
@Stateless
public class PostSessionBean {

  public Program getProgramById(int programId) {

String programById = "select p from Program p where p.id = :id";
Program program = null;
try {
  Query query = em.createQuery(programById);
  query.setParameter("id", programId);
  program = (Program) query.getSingleResult();
```

I do get the correcct program entity with data, but the list with 
multi_kupon data is size 0

What im i doing wrong here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping is incorrect, as you have specified both that the OneToMany is mappedBy = "program" and that it should use join columns.  Only one or the other should be used, and since there is a 'program' mapping, I suggest you use:

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "program", fetch =  FetchType.EAGER)
  public List getMultiKuponList()

And then define the join columns on MultiKupon's ManyToOne mapping to define which fields should be used for the foreign keys to the Program table.

Since you have made this a bidirectional relationship, you must also maintain both sides of your relationship.  This means that every time you add a MultiKupon and want it associated to a Program you must both have it reference the Program, AND add the instance to the Program's collection.  If you do not, you will run into this situation, where the cached Program is out of sync with what is in the database.

It is much cheaper generally to keep both sides in sync, but if this is not an option, you can correct the issue (or just verify that this is the situation) by calling em.refresh(program).  If the mappings are setup correctly, the instance and its list will be repopulated with what is in the database.

Comment: You were absolutely right, Chris. I removed the JoinColumns on program - but put it on MultiKupon and now it works. Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

According to http://sysout.be/2011/03/09/why-you-should-never-use-getsingleresult-in-jpa/

Try to retrieve first program object of List:

```
List<Program> pList = query.getResultList();
if(!pList.isEmpty()){
   return pList.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Same result - size of collection MultiKupon is 0 - But thanks for the reply

Comment: I tried to set the `@JoinFetch` below the `@ManyToOne` in MultiKupon, but still size = 0

Comment: Are you sure there's required db records in the table??

Comment: Yes im sure - did a select with join and got the expected data